# How to add a shortcode on a specific page based on the url parameter

Tags: php, function, woocommerce, filter, shortcode

I would like to add a custom content before the WooCommerce shop loop if a specific filter is active.

The example url is this: `/shop/?filter_brand=nike`

So far I have tried with this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'amc_add_content_before_loop' );
function amc_add_content_before_loop() {
    if ( is_product_category('nike') ) {
        echo esc_html__("Custom content", "amc");
    }
}
```

But the content is not shown on the page.

**EDIT**

With Vincenzo's answer now it works.
I am now trying to use variables and add a shortcode. I tried with this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'add_custom_content_before_shop_loop2' );
function add_custom_content_before_shop_loop2() {
    $terms = get_terms( 'pa_brand' );
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        if ( is_shop() && isset( $_GET['filter_brand'] ) && $_GET['filter_brand'] == $term->name ) {
            echo do_shortcode('[block id="brand-'.$term->name.'"]');
        }
    }
}
```

So what it supposed to do is, if a filter `$term->name` is active, a custom shortcode with the `$term->name` should be echoed.

But it's not working.

Comment: Is `brand` a native attribute of the products?

Comment: It is a created global attribute within the woocommerce spectrum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the url you posted: `/shop/?filter_brand=nike`, you can do it like this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'add_custom_content_before_shop_loop' );
function add_custom_content_before_shop_loop() {

    if ( is_shop() && isset( $_GET['filter_brand'] ) && $_GET['filter_brand'] == 'nike' ) {
        // add custom content
    }

}
```

*The code has been tested and works. Add it to your active theme's functions.php file.*

**EDIT**

To get the `pa_brand` attribute name you are using `$term->name` instead of `$term->slug`.

`$term` is an instance of the [`WP_Term`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term/) class. The structure of the [`WP_Term`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term/) object can be found [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term/).

Try with this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'add_custom_content_before_shop_loop2' );
function add_custom_content_before_shop_loop2() {
    $terms = get_terms( 'pa_brand' );
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        if ( is_shop() && isset( $_GET['filter_brand'] ) && $_GET['filter_brand'] == $term->slug ) {
            echo do_shortcode('[block id="brand-'.$term->slug.'"]');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you that worked great, I added another question in the thread, maybe you can help me with that as well!